# Why is my favicon appearing on Amazon S3 endpoint but not on the forwarded domain?

Tags: amazon-s3, favicon

I have tried everything possible and am out of ideas as to why my favicon is still not appearing. If I told you how much time I've spent trying to figure this out you'd understand why i'm on the verge of losing my mind.

Here's the rundown [i'm not technical- just starting to learn so please bear with me]:

I'm using Amazon S3 as my host. GoDaddy is the DNS and I have forwarding with a mask setup so that the amazon endpoint is directed to the actual domain.

Here's the strange thing-- the favicon appears on the amazon endpoint but doesn't on the forwarded domain which is where I want it to appear. The favicon also appears when I do some testing using Dreamweaver.

I can assure you that it isn't a matter a clearing the cache as I've done that numerous times and have ran tests to make sure that it's working. I've tried all the possible different types of variations of code and nothing works. I'm led to believe that it's not an issue with the code, cache, file but rather something else that is out of my realm of knowledge.

So I come to Stackoverflow.

Please-- any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: what code are you trying to use?

Comment: @MattWhipple here is the code: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> or <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico"> i've tried both in all possible variations and even uploaded .png and .jpeg files and made adjustments to see if that would work but it didn't!

Comment: @MattWhipple but if it was an issue in the code it wouldn't appear on the amazon endpoint or in dreamweaver when testing, right?

Comment: It depends on how things may be proxied.  If you stick to a fully qualified, known good URL then it should eliminate that question.  You may also be better off putting the favicon in a particular directory rather than trying to get it to work from the host root.

Comment: @MattWhipple when you say "sticking to a fully qualified, known good URL" does that mean not having to use DNS forwarding? Is that possible with Amazon S3? Also, would an edit to CORS solve this issue?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  If you go to your goDaddy domain and do 'View Page Source' you will see something like this:
'<frame src="http://example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/" frameborder="0" />'

The favicon metadata gets lost because the page is in an iframe.

Comment: @fireydude I am facing the same issue too.. did you find any way to work around that?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone having such problem - making the favicon public and using a direct link found in the file's properties on s3 did the charm.

Answer (score 0):

That means use a full URL that is always going to work from everywhere.  Depending on how things are set-up a hostname could resolve to something like localhost on multiple machines, so you want to make sure that the host name you're using always has the resource at that location.  CORS should have anything to do with it as it is a standard full GET request.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: To start with you may be best off just hosting the favicon on a server external to S3 to eliminate variability.  So upload the icon to anywhere that it has a public URL, and then try using that URL.  And then you'd probably want to switch the URL to use the actual S3 bucket address rather than any form of alias.